# alignment issue with RecyclerView in android 4.4

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-recyclerview

I am implementing a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) in my application and it is working. But i am facing a problem with the list item alignment in Recyclerview.

actually my list item have a image view and a text view. i need some space between the each list item. like this

[image]

With this Relative layout i am able to get my expected result. But for spacing between the items i used the **[RecyclerView.ItemDecoration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html)**

Here is my list_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#65FF0000"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_icon"
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_icon"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

insted of using the [RecyclerView.ItemDecoration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html) i tried the in the below way but it is not worked.Here is my list_item.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#90FF0000"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_icon"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#90FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But i am getting the view like below

[image]

Where exactly i am making the mistake.. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: i updated my question and posted the expected result too @Marcus

Comment: So you want an list item with an image/icon and two text view one under another which are aligned to right of icon?

Comment: only one text view i needed. second text view i given to make the space between the list items @Android Developer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well finally, I got the solution for my question.

In my RecyclerView adapter previously i used the below type of approach to create the list items

```
 public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent,
            int viewType )
    {
         // create a new view
        itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from( parent.getContext() ).inflate( R.layout.list_row_serch,
                                                                             null );

        // create ViewHolder
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder( itemLayoutView );

        return viewHolder;
    }
```

After changing it as like below it is working fine. even if it a Releative/Linear layout

```
  public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent,
            int viewType )
    {

        itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from( parent.getContext() ).inflate( R.layout.list_row_serch,
                                                                             parent,
                                                                             false );

        // create ViewHolder
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder( itemLayoutView );

        return viewHolder;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So as I understand from your question you want your `RecyclerView`'s items to look like this:

[image]

Here is a simple layout which will create this look (using `RelativeLayout`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="10dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_avatar"
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/user_avatar"
        android:gravity="left"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the version using `LinearLayout` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:padding="10dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_avatar"
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="left"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you want space between two `RecyclerView` items no need to add another `TextView` just include `padding` to your main container in `list_item.xml`

Comment: See the edited answer for version using `LinearLayout`.

Comment: relative layout is working perfectly. but linear layout not working.. any way thanks for the help

Comment: what is the problem with LinearLayout? I've tested the both versions and the output is the same.

Comment: So you want to add separator between the items? If yes you should use `ItemDecorator` as you said in your question. That's the right way to do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77179/discussion-between-gangulian-and-android-developer).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make the list item fill the whole width of its parent.

As below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#90FF0000"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/item_icon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/item_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#90FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: See my updated answer. You will have to adjust the weigh so it fit your needs. @Gangulian

Comment: before posting the question itself, i tried all that combinations @Marcus. Not worked for me